# JQuery - Selecting a div from a table row using data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table (with id = cards) and inside it number of table rows (with data-row index) inside each row there are number of divs (with class = card, and data-col and data-value). I am trying to retrieve a (row,column) data-value. Here what I have

```
$('#cards tr').eq(flipped.r+1).children(".card").find("[data-col = '"+flipped.c+"']").data("value")
```

However I am stuck not getting the specific div's data-value

Comment: add html mark up. also add all relevant code to OP.. Like `flipped var`

Comment: @guradio flipped.r and flipped.c are the row and column, my issue that after the "children(".card")" part, I can not select the specific div I want. Everything else works fine

Comment: is `.card` the td with `data-col` then you should use `$('#cards tr').eq(flipped.r+1).children(".card[data-col = '"+flipped.c+"']").data("value")`